# How to use a method to swipe between activities?

Tags: java, android, layout, touch, swipe

I have two activities with two different layouts.Right now i have to click a button to change to the other layout, but i wanna to swipe on the screen, is that possible?

Comment: why not do things the right way and use a `ViewPager`

Comment: @tyczj  Please post that as an answer so i can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your two layouts as Fragments, then you can use the ViewPager to swipe between the fragments in the same activity.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html